# How do I make XhtmlTextWriter write a newline before an open tag immediately preceeded by a close tag?

Tags: c#

I'm using an XhtmlTextWriter to write out some Xtml along the following lines:

```
XhtmlTextWriter writer = // init writer;
writer.WriteLineNoTabs(
    "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
writer.AddAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
writer.AddAttribute("xml:lang", "en");
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
writer.Write("My Title");
writer.RenderEndTag(); // Title

writer.RenderEndTag(); // Head

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);


writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H3);
writer.WriteLine("My Heading", userName);
writer.RenderEndTag(); // H3

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.H6);
writer.WriteLine("My Sub-heading");
writer.RenderEndTag(); // H6

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Hr);
writer.RenderEndTag(); // Hr

writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.P);
writer.WriteLine("Hello World.");
writer.RenderEndTag(); // P

writer.RenderEndTag(); // Body

writer.RenderEndTag(); // Html
```

What I get in the output is something like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            My Title
        </title>
    </head><body>
        <h3>
            My Heading

        </h3><h6>
            My Sub-heading

        </h6><hr /><p>Hello World.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

While this is valid Xhtml I was expecting a newline between tags like `</head>` and `<body>`. I would make the resulting Xhtml easier to read, for one thing.

Is there a way I can get the XtmlTextWriter to do this?

I messed around a bit with overriding `RenderAfterTag` and similar, but since the lack of newline is only in the case of a close tag followed immediately by an open tag it was not immediately obvious how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

`writer.WriteLine()` without args writes a newline character to the output stream

Comment: That's true, but I was looking to do it programmatically (utilizing the existing formatting provided by XtmlTextWriter) as opposed to having to identify the places where I'm closing one tag followed by opening another and manually inserting a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `HtmlTextWriter` which wraps `RenderEndTag` and simply writes a new line every time you call it.

```
public static class extensions {

    public static void myRenderEndTag (this HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

Here it is in action with a usable and abbreviated version of your code:

```
using (var textWriter = File.CreateText("test.txt")) 
using (XhtmlTextWriter writer = new XhtmlTextWriter(textWriter)) {

    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
      writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
          writer.Write("My Title");
        writer.myRenderEndTag(); // Title
      writer.myRenderEndTag(); // Head
      writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
      writer.myRenderEndTag(); // Body
    writer.myRenderEndTag(); // Html

}
```